# Addin Custom Fields to Customer Table

Tags: magento-1.8, customer, php-5.4

I'm adding Custom field/Column to Customer table. but it's not showing in table as well as customer grid from admin panel.

my code is:

**C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Customer\etc\config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mage_Customer>
            <version>1.6.2.0.2</version>
        </Mage_Customer>
    </modules>
    <admin>
        <fieldsets>
            <customer_dataflow>
                <mobile>
                    <billing>1</billing>
                    <shipping>1</shipping>
                    <mapped>1</mapped>
                </mobile>
            </customer_dataflow>
        </fieldsets>
    </admin>
    <global>
        <fieldsets>
            <customer_account>               
                <Mobile>
                    <create>1</create>
                    <update>1</update>
                </Mobile>
            </customer_account>        
        </fieldsets>
   .....
</config>
```

**C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Customer\Model\Resource\Setup.php**

```
<?php

class Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Setup extends Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup
{
    ...

 public function getDefaultEntities()
    {
        $entities = array(
            'customer'                       => array(
                'entity_model'                   => 'customer/customer',
                'attribute_model'                => 'customer/attribute',
                'table'                          => 'customer/entity',
                'increment_model'                => 'eav/entity_increment_numeric',
                'additional_attribute_table'     => 'customer/eav_attribute',
                'entity_attribute_collection'    => 'customer/attribute_collection',
                'attributes'                     => array(

                    'mobile'             => array(
                        'type'               => 'int',
                        'label'              => 'mobile',
                        'input'              => 'text',
                        'required'           => false,
                        'sort_order'         => 111,
                        'position'           => 111,
                        'visible'            => true,
                    ),

                )
            ),

        );
        return $entities;
    }    
    ...       
}
```

**C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Customer\sql\customer_setup\upgrade-1.6.2.0-1.6.2.0.2.php**

```
<?php


$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$this->addAttribute('customer', 'mobile', array(

    'type' => 'varchar',

    'input' => 'text',

    'label' => 'mobile',

    'global' => 1,

    'visible' => 1,

    'required' => 0,

    'user_defined' => 1,

    'visible_on_front' => 1

));

Mage::log('Working');

$installer->endSetup();

$customerattribute = Mage::getModel('customer/attribute')->loadByCode('customer','mobile');
$forms = array('customer_register_address',
    'customer_address_edit',
    'adminhtml_customer_address');
$customerattribute->setData('used_in_forms',$forms);

$customerattribute->save();
```

Could you please tell me where I went wrong?

thanks in advance.

Comment: You really should namespace that attribute code. I could see "mobile" as an easy collision down the road.

Comment: @benmarks, any way working fine. but I have question regarding this. actually this field value is save on `customer_entity_varchar` but this Column is Where will create?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately you need to add your attribute to the grid collection and link that field to a new column in the grid block. Normally this is done by modifying a couple of `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Grid` grid block methods, `_prepareCollection()` and `_prepareColumns()`. In the case of this grid though I think that you can modify the `_afterLoadCollection()` method in order to reduce code duplication and increase version portability:

```
protected function _afterLoadCollection()
{
    if ($this->getCollection()) {

        //allows collection to be modified & reload from DB
        $this->getCollection()->clear(); 

        //re-load() collection
        $this->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('mobile')->load();
    }

    return parent::_afterLoadCollection();
}
```

Column logic overriding is easier:

```
protected function _prepareColumns()
{
    //execute original columns, which will execute sorting
    parent::_prepareColumns();

    //add your column with the ability to have final say in sort precedence
    $this->addColumn(
        'mobile',
        array( ... )
    )

    //re-run sorting
    $this->sortColumnsByOrder();

    //maintain fluent interface
    return $this;
}
```

Note that this is pseudocode which I have not tried. Also, note my comment regarding attribute code namespacing. "mobile" is ripe for collisions.

Comment: any way working fine. but I have question regarding this. actually this field value is save on `customer_entity_varchar` but this Column is Where will create?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by *"but this Column is Where will create"*. To understand more about your attribute's behaviors, you need to find its record in the `eav_attribute` table.